# "Eahna" auf Bairisch

Tags: slang, bavarian

I speak quite good German but have lived in Vienna for a while before moving to Bayern, so my "Bairisch" is not really very good. Today a Bavarian said to me *"Das ist für Eahna"*, now I thought that "Eahna" was Bairisch for "Ihnen", ie the dative of "Sie", so I was surprised to hear it used after "für" where I would have expected the accusative "Sie". I have asked several Bavarian friends and colleagues but nobody could explain it. They all just said it can be used like that and it's just Bairisch. Could someone here explain the rules for using "Eahna" in Bairisch?

Comment: Not sure there's all that much to explain, really. It's dialect für _Ihnen_, as you have stated correctly. The rest is just using dative instead of the accusative (as would be correct in standard German). This happens often, you'll also hear "Für we*m*" etc. on occasion.

Comment: Note that Bavarian uses "fia" as a preposition translating to both "vor" (acc. or dat.) and "für" (acc.), a *mittelhochdeutsch* remnant. The separation of "vor" and "für" in standard German happened later.

Comment: Wenn du gut Deutsch sprichst, warum stellst du deine Frage dann auf Englisch? Das hier ist ein Deutsch-Forum und mehr als 95% aller Fragen werden von deutschen Muttersprachler beantwortet. Und gerade Fragen über Dialekte sind ein Themengebiet, das vor allem Personen interessiert, die entweder deutsche Muttersprachler sind bereits so gut Deutsch sprechen, dass sie mühelos einer deutschsprachigen Erklärung folgen können.

Comment: Im Ruhrgebiet heißt es auch schon mal "Wer ist die Currywurst?" und als Antwort kommt "Mich!" Dat is einfach so.

Comment: Es könnte natürlich daran liegen dass ich einige Monate in Bayern verbracht habe und auch viel Kontakt zu Oberösterreichern habe, aber für mich als Niederösterreicher klingt diese Formulierung im Dialekt nicht überraschend, und es würde mich nicht einmal wundern, so etwas schon knapp außerhalb der Wiener Stadtgrenze zu hören (natürlich "leichte" lokale Variationen, "Eahna", "Ihna", "Ihnan" etc.).

Comment: Reges Interesse an der Frage, aber kein Upvote - what's wrong with you, guys? Nur, weil die Frage auf Englisch gestellt wurde - das kann es wohl kaum sein, bei der gemeinen Englischpräferenz. Eine vernünftige Frage, ordentlich erklärt,..

Comment: @HubertSchölnast The only rule I am aware of is that answers should ideally match the language of the question. I think it is inappropriate to ask others to justify why they'd make any particular choice between English and German in asking their question.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Firstly,you make no attempt to answer my question. Secondly, this is not a "Deutsch-Forum" as you claim, its title is "German Language" in English and not "Die deutsche Sprache". The majority of questions on this forum are asked in the English language and I see no reason why I should have to explain to you why I chose to ask my question in English. Have you considered that maybe I felt I could frame my question better in my mother tongue, or perhaps I was preparing for a complicated answer which would have been above my capabilities to understand in German.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich stimme mit Deinem Kommentar nicht überein und betrachte ihn als Äußerung persönlicher Vorlieben. Es gibt hier keine Sprachen-Präferenz, siehe *bilingual* in der [Tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) und ich sehe auch keine zwingende Implikation dafür aus dem Thema der Frage.

Comment: @Steve: While you have a point here (see my comment to Hubert), not attempting to answer within a comment is  pretty normal - just answers should answer.

Comment: Just for completeness: I made an attempt to answer this question and I wrote it the same time I wrote my previous comment here. You just can't see it because I did not post it. (Maybe moderators can see it? I don't know. It's stored in the system.) I wrote 5 paragraphs, but I didn't post this attempt so far because my answer is not finished, I have much other things to do at the moment. I will post my answer once it's finished. But I have written my attempt in German and I will not translate it into English.

Answer (score 3):

As Ingmar pointed out, it is dialect for *Das ist für Ihnen*. The only confusing thing -- as you correctly found out -- is: Why the word *Ihnen* here? Well, there is also nothing to explain, just get it as dialectical answer to accusative. *Für wen? Für Ihnen*, although you would expect *Für Sie* in Upper German. In the end, it really means *Das ist für Sie*.

Note that this is not to be confused with the plural, lower-case *sie*, which in dialect is *Für se*.

Source: My mother tongue.